# Query Helm based deployment from a Kubernetes cluster using Restful API

Tags: rest, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

We have a usecase where we need to get the deploy values and the chart numbers of a given K8S cluster. For Kubernetes we have a client or some restful APIs exposed, but for Helm we couldn't find anything.

We can build a microservice the will do it, however, it's something which we would like to avoid as it boils down to more development and support for something that I guess already out there.

I would appriciate any help.

Thanks!

Comment: You can [embed Helm as a library](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/topics/advanced/#go-sdk); as of Helm 3 there's (thankfully!) no longer a cluster-side component you can integrate with.  Remember that you generally need RBAC permissions to read Secrets to use Helm, and you can in effect read any object content that Helm would have created (you can read or recreate the object manifest) which may have security implications for you.

Comment: Based on your answer David, we've deployed helm-wrapper which uses the helm library (go based) and it works amazing! cheers! finally we have some workaround for restful apis abilities.